# Wird "ad hoc" im Allgemeinen verstanden?

Tags: loanword

Wenn ein Begriff, noch dazu ein entlehnter, in einer Fachsprache häufig verwendet wird, heißt das noch nicht, dass er außerhalb der Fachsprache verstanden wird. Meine Frage ist nun, ob man davon ausgehen kann, dass "ad hoc" allgemein verstanden wird (im Sinne von "ohne Vorbereitung, aus dem Stegreif etc.").

Hintergrund: In einer Software kann ein Anwender "Dinge" verwalten, z. B. mit anderen Dingen verknüpfen. Im Allgemeinen werden diese Dinge dafür aus einer "Bibliothek" entnommen. Die Dinge in der Bibliothek sind Standarddinge, die immer wieder verwendet werden. In speziellen Fällen kann der Anwender aber auch ein Ding in dem Moment "erzeugen", indem er es mit einem anderen Ding verknüpfen will. Dieses "Ad hoc Ding" ist dann nicht Teil der Bibliothek und wird nach dem Auflösen der Verknüpfung im Nichts verschwinden, weil es nur für diesen speziellen Anwendungsfall gebraucht wird.

Comment: Nein. Mit Sicherheit nicht.

Comment: Zumal ich die Definition "ohne Vorbereitung, aus dem Stegreif" nicht ganz richtig finde, da beides eine andere Konnotation hat, als die, die du in dem anschließenden Beispiel aufzeigst. Aber das ist nur ne Randnotiz.

Comment: Kannst Du das näher erläutern? Wo siehst Du Unterschiede?

Comment: Sollte die Frage nicht eher lauten, ob die *Zielgruppe* es versteht?

Comment: Erstmal zur Definition: [„Aus dem Stegreif“ bedeutet wörtlich: ohne vom Pferd zu steigen, im übertragenen Sinn: ohne lang nachzudenken, unvorbereitet, extemporiert, improvisiert.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stegreif). Das bedeutet also, man machts einfach "mal eben so". Soweit so gut, gilt ja auch im weitesten Sinne für "ad hoc", aber ich verstehe den Begriff eher als "einmalig", "speziell eingerichtet/angelegt/whatever". Verstehst du, worauf ich hinaus will?

Comment: @Jan Erstmal gibt es mehrere Zielgruppen. Und grundsätzlich, auch wenn du zur Zielgruppe gehörst, verstehst du nicht zwingend alle Begriffe, aber man kann davon ausgehen, wenn ein Begriff regelmäßig im Umfeld erwähnt/verwendet wird.

Comment: @Em1: Du sagst dass es für diese Software mehrere Zielgruppen gibt - offenbar bist hast Du mir gegenüber da einen Wissensvorsprung. Ich kenne die Software nicht... Aber ja, mein Kommentar zielte genau darauf ab, dass ein Begriff dann mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit einem Mitglied einer Zielgruppe bekannt ist, wenn er in ihrem typischen Umfeld oft oder regelmäßig verwendet wird.

Comment: @Jan Nicht Software, sondern der Begriff an sich.

Comment: @Em1: Entschuldige bitte, diesen Kommentar habe ich leider nicht verstanden. Kannst Du ihn bitte etwas näher ausführen?

Comment: Hmm. DWDS erläutert "ad hoc" als "eigens für diesen Zweck" und das ist auch die Bedeutung innerhalb der Software. Ich bin wankelmütig...

Comment: @Jan Du hast geschrieben "Du sagst dass es für diese Software mehrere Zielgruppen gibt - offenbar bist hast Du mir gegenüber da einen Wissensvorsprung." Ich wollte nur sagen, dass ich mich auf den Begriff "ad hoc" beziehe. Also es gibt mehrere Zielgruppen, die nichts miteinander zu tuen haben, die den Begriff "ad hoc" gebrauchen. Eine Zielgruppe ist die IT.

Comment: @EricSchaefer War dein letzter Kommentar wieder an mich gerichtet? Falls ja, finde ich, dass "eigens für diesen Zweck" meine Aussage bestärkt. Aber letztlich ist es auch egal, weil es eh nur eine *Randnotiz* war und hier gar nicht weiter diskutiert werden sollte.

Comment: Welche Fachsprache soll das sein, in der 'ad hoc' verwendet wird? Ich kannte den Begriff lange bevor ich mit IT zu tun hattte.

Comment: @userunknown Vllt hattest du Latein in der Schule? Ich hab den Begriff tatsächlich erst durch den IT-Bezug kennengelernt.

Comment: @Em1: Nein, weder Latein, noch Griechisch. Aber relativ viel Literatur i.d. Freizeit gelesen.

Comment: @Em1: ah, da liegt der Hund begraben! Ich verstehe unter "Zielgruppe" tatsächlich die definierte Nutzergruppe, die die Software bedienen können soll, also z.B. "die Mitglieder der IT-Abteilung von Firma xyz" für interne Software, oder sowas wie "gelernte Buchhalter oder Controller mit mindestens durchschnittlichen PC-Kenntnissen", wenn es sich beispielsweise um eine frei verkäufliche Buchhaltungs-Software handelt.

Comment: Siehe auch [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) für mehr Infos zum Thema User Experience und nutzerzentrierte Gestaltung.

Comment: @Em1: Inwiefern hat denn "ad hoc" einen IT-Bezug? Ich kenne das Wort eher aus der Alltagssprache (und Latein habe ich nie gelernt), und auch wenn ich mir vorstellen könnte, dass man "ad hoc" IT-bezogen gebrauchen könnte (z.B., um sich "ad hoc" ein Skript für eine aktuelle Aufgabe zu schreiben), wüsste ich jetzt auf Anhieb erst mal nicht, inwiefern es IT-spezifisch wäre.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ad hoc würde ich sagen: Es wird allgemein verstanden.

Im Speziellen fragte ich mich, aus welcher Fachsprache *ad hoc* sein soll. Ich kann es keinem Fachgebiet zuordnen.

Die einzige Einschränkung, die ich machen würde: Ich würde nicht erwarten, dass *ad hoc* in jeder Bevölkerungsschicht verstanden wird. Eine gewisse Bildung würde ich voraussetzen.

Zusammengefasst: Nicht jeder versteht *ad hoc*, aber ich würde es von jedem etwas Gebildeten erwarten.

Comment: Dem stimme ich auch zu. Ich würde von jedem Abiturienten erwarten, dass er es versteht, und vom Großteil der Nichtabiturienten auch.

Comment: Auch ich vermute, dass es der weitaus überwiegende Bevölkerungsteil verstehen dürfte. Randnotiz: In der englischen Fachsprache wird z.B. das Wort "adhocracy" (in Abgrenzung zur "bureaucracy") im Bereich der Wirtschaftswissenschaften schon lange verwendet. Es taucht sogar mittlerweile in soziologischen Kontexten auf (bezogen auf social sites & open source). Die Wendung "ad hoc" habe ich in Form der "Adhocracy" auch schon in deutschen Texten gefunden.

Answer (score 7):

Das [DWDS-Korpus listet Beispiele](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ad%20hoc&view=1), die eindeutig nix mit Programmierung zu tun haben. Daher kann man sagen, es wird verstanden … die gleiche Quelle nennt den Gebrauch "gehoben“ … daher wird es vielleicht nicht immer verstanden.
Ich persönlich kannte das Wort, ohne um seine Nutzung in der Informatik zu wissen.

Comment: Deine Antwort tendiert zu einem "JA". Dem stimme ich aber nicht zu. Generell, so meine Erfahrung, sind Begriff, die aus anderen Sprachen entlehnt sind, nicht zwingend bekannt. Dazu gehört "ad hoc" mit Sicherheit auch. Ausnahmen stellen Begriffe wie "et cetera" dar, wobei selbst da hab ich oft den Eindruck, dass viele es einfach nur benutzen, weil sie es schon tausend mal gehört/gesehen haben, aber noch nie hinterfragt haben, was es eigentlich genau bedeutet und woher es kommt.

Comment: kann schon sein, dass du recht hast, aber wenn es danach geht, dann ist das eine reine Meinungsfrage und sollte geschlossen werden.... ich wollte nur zeigen, dass der Begriff ausserhalb des von Eric gegebenen Kontextes in den Medien auftritt. Das ist meiner Ansicht nach neben dem Duden die einzige Möglichkeit einer objektiven Beantwortung. Wenn's nach Gefühl geht, dann gibt es auch Leute die Interdependenz nicht verstehen oder gar fürderhin ... wonach will man da jetzt allgemein entscheiden... also, ich werde jetzt ein close voten

Comment: Gute Argumentation, ich schließe mich an.

Comment: "gehoben" ist kein Ausschlusskriterium, da die Anwender ausnahmslos qualifizierte Fachkräfte sind.

Comment: @EricSchaefer: diese Information (die Anwender sind ausnahmslos qualifizierte Fachkräfte [welches Fach?]) wäre in der Fragestellung hilfreich gewesen...

Answer (score 4):

*Ad hoc* fällt mir jetzt keine Zielgruppe ein, die diesen Begriff an sich nicht verstehen sollte. Sicher ist es ein Begriff, den man nicht jeden Tag liest oder gebraucht, jedoch zeigt ein Google Ngram, dass der Begriff *"[ad hoc](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ad_hoc)"* verglichen mit Alternativen wie *"zu diesem Zweck"* und *"spontan"* nicht so selten ist und sogar häufiger vorkommt als *"Stegreif"*.

[image]

Dennoch bin ich der Meinung, dass der Begriff *"ad hoc"* in der Fachsprache der Datenverwaltung **mit anderer Bedeutung** eingesetzt wird, als in der Allgemeinsprache und von einem (Datenbank-) Laien deshalb auch nicht eindeutig und richtig verstanden werden kann.

**Man muss es deshalb dem Benutzer erklären.**

Comment: In welcher Bedeutung wird `ad hoc` denn in der IT verwendet? Als Programmierer ist es für mich dringend das zu verstehen, denn ich benutze den Begriff ständig i.d. allgemeinen Bedeutung.

Answer (score 1):

Your headline asks "*Wird “ad hoc” im allgemeinen verstanden?*" Regarding that I definitively say *No, not at large*.

Nonetheless, in the context you gave I think it's very likely that "ad hoc" is known but I also advise to explain the term.
Though, I'm not 100% clear about the context. If you're talking about the user of the software they may not know the word. That is, if there is a button the user can press labeled "*Create Ad-Hoc Dingsbums*" than you can likely create just some question marks on his forehead. However, if you're talking about the person who provides or developed the software the possibility of knowing such a word increases.

All the others who commented or answered the question mentioned that they already knew "ad hoc" for a long time and not from a special context (like IT). Me, I just know the term since I heard it in my (IT) studies. And I know a lot of people who aren't aware of the term.

Independent from this context, I recommend not to require any (technical) term or word that is borrowed from another language. There will always be one person, at the very least, who don't know the word. And for those people you should explain the word the first time you use it. Of course, make it short so that others don't get bored or irritated of the - for them - "useless" explanation.

Last but not least think of our little conversation about the definition of this term, and [Takkat mentioned in his answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4556/1224) that in a certain context the word is used subtly differently, too. Thus, to avoid misconception, explain the word how you comprehend and use the word.

Answer (score 1):

"Ad hoc" wird allgemein verstanden. Während es richtig ist, dass es nicht absolut jeder verstehen wird, ist es ganz sicher nicht ungebräuchlicher oder unverständlicher als "aus dem Stegreif".

Etwas subtiler ist allerdings, dass Begriffe wie "ad hoc", "spontan", "aus dem Stegreif" nicht synonym verwendet werden.

Comment: worauf basiert dein Statement?

Answer (score 1):

Dein Ziel, Eric, ist es vermutlich einen Begriff zu finden der alle Aspekte des ad hoc-Dings möglichst komplett erfasst. Für mich sind das

- spontane Erstellung ohne Rückgriff auf Bibliothek
- Ende des Dings wenn das Partnerobjekt (Elternobjekt?) nicht mehr existiert.

Der Begriff "Ad hoc" erfasst für mich den ersten Aspekt recht gut, aber leider den zweiten irgendwie gar nicht.
Das heißt: Du wirst sowieso irgendwo genauer erklären müssen, wie der Mechanismus genau funktioniert und kannst auch genauso gut einen anderen Begriff wählen, der vielleicht von mehr Menschen verstanden wird. Mir fallen da Begriffe wie "Spontan-Dings" oder "sofort-Dings" ein. Wenn die Lebendauer des Ad hoc-Dings relativ kurz ist, dann könnte man auch "tempöräres Dings" sagen.

Diese Begriffe erfassen leider auch nicht beide Aspekte komplett, aber je nach Hörer sind sie vielleicht eingängiger.

Comment: Die Frage von Eric war recht klar und es ging NICHT darum einen Begriff zu finden. Daher -1